# JBoss 4.0.5 MDB Configuration

Tags: jboss, jboss-mdb, jbossmq

This one is beating me, and I have not been able to figure it out ... So here it goes.
I want to add a Message Drive Bean to my app which is packaged as a .ear file

Following the documentation I've created a jboss.xml and a ejb-jar.xml, which I tried to put on the META-INF and the root and on the WEB-INF but I just don;t see it working (i.e. the MDB is never loaded, nor it received the messages.

My ear file looks like:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/application.xml
myapp.war
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution was to separate the MDB code (and supporting classes) into a separate file inside the ear (myapp-mdb.jar) And to support that with the same hibernate mappings and classes, the hibernate related files were packaged on the myapp.har.

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
META-INF\application.xml
META-INF\jboss-app.xml
myapp-mdb.jar
myapp.har
myapp.war
```

Just posting the answer for reference.